# How can I turn a html new line into FastReport.frx new line on FastReport versions before 2018?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, report, fastreport

I turned an html editor text to fastreport pdf text. I used regex to make html tags like color tags and bold character tag to match FastReport tags.

While making new lines I tried to match 
 and /n and /r/n and even the character CLRL which notepad++ showed me. I couldn't find a way to make a new line on FastReport.

Does anyone knows a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I only copied the CLRL part where you make a new line in a text which notepad++ showed me. And it worked!! Writing CLRL somehow doesnt work but copying the part where it starts from the last of the line and starts of the next works.

[image]